# Tshark - can't display just data of custom protocol

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

I have a custom protocol that runs on port 8888 (no, it's not http) and on top of TCP. I've captured the flow of packets into the PCAP file. The problem is that now I cannot display just the data portion of it.

I've tried with the following command:

```
tshark -r test.pcap -R 'tcp.port==8888 && tcp.len>0' -T fields -e "tcp.data"
```

But it displays an empty strings. Isn't the **tcp.data** field the one that holds the data of the TCP packet?

How can I display only the data that I need?

Comment: You may want to give [`tpcick`](http://tcpick.sourceforge.net/) a try

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, tcpick has one limitation though: it doesn't support ipv6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is "Analyze/Follow TCP stream" functionality in Wireshark.

Just select TCP packet from the packet list and then "Follow TCP stream".... and Wireshark displays the TCP conversation of the selected connection.

EDIT:

`tcp.data` does not exist. Use `data.data` instead:

```
tshark -r mon.pcap -R "(tcp.port == 8888) && (tcp.len > 0)" -T  fields -e data.data
```

If wireshark knows the protocol which uses the port (8888), then the previous won't work.
But the following trick works:

```
tshark -r mon.pcap -R "(tcp.port == 8888) && (tcp.len > 0)" -T  fields -d tcp.port==8888,echo -e echo.data
```

Comment: Yes I know about that, but I don't want to use it since it's a bit impractical, because it only shows the TCP conversation of selected connection. I want to display whole TCP conversation of the selected IPs. If you know a way to do that in Wireshark I'll gladly use it.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, it really helps. The first command prints the data portion of the protocol, but in hex. And since it's ASCII protocol it would be much better to print the printable characters in their ascii representation, and non-printabled with a dot '.'. Example of the output is: "45:58:49:54:0d:ff", which is "EXIT??" as can be seen here: http://www.dolcevie.com/js/converter.html . So basically this is all that needs to be done now. Do you know if tshark supports this?

Comment: I don't know. But remember: TCP can do retansmissions. So, sometimes there can occur partly duplicated data in the output.

Comment: I echo @eleanor's question.  There is `data` -- one whole packet of strings as Hex nibbles and there is `data.data` which looks like a sequence (or array) of bytes. How does one get the ASCII for "EXIT" instead of the long string of hex nibbles?  Surely there must be a solution internal to `tshark` or a tool I can pipe my output to ...???

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've programmed a python script that does the needed job. I know the code could be a little better, but it works and it's all I need for now.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import sys
import binascii

""" Input arguments. """
if len(sys.argv) != 3 and len(sys.argv) != 4 and len(sys.argv)!= 5:
  print "[*] You didn't specify the right command line arguments."
  print "Usage:\n"
  print "\t"+sys.argv[0]+" <pcap> <port> [<src_ip> <dst_ip>]"
  print
  exit(-1)

args = len(sys.argv)
if args == 3:
  pcap = sys.argv[1]
  port = sys.argv[2]
elif args == 4:
  pcap = sys.argv[1]
  port = sys.argv[2]
  srcip = sys.argv[3]
elif args == 5:
  pcap = sys.argv[1]
  port = sys.argv[2]
  srcip = sys.argv[3]
  dstip = sys.argv[4]


""" Use tshark to read pcap file. """
targs = []
targs.append("tshark")
targs.append("-r"+pcap)
f = "-R (tcp.port=="+port+") && (tcp.len>0)"
if args == 4:
  f=f+" && (ip.src == "+srcip+")"
elif args == 5:
  f=f+" && (ip.src == "+srcip+" and ip.dst == "+dstip+")"
targs.append(f)
targs.append("-Tfields")
targs.append("-edata.data")
p = subprocess.Popen(targs, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
  """ Read a line of output from the tshark output- """
  out = p.stdout.readline()

  """ Print only non-empty lines."""
  if out != '':
    """ Parse the line appropriately and print printable characters. """
    chars = out.split(':')
    for c in chars:
      if c >= '20' and c <= '7e':
    try:
          cc = binascii.unhexlify(c)
    except:
      pass
    sys.stdout.write(cc)
      else:
        sys.stdout.write('.')
    print

  """ When there is no more data, break out of infinite loop."""
  if out == '' and p.poll() != None:
    break

p.stdout.close()
```

We can call the script three different ways:

First:

```
python tshark.py temp.pcap 8888
```

Second:

```
python tshark.py temp.pcap 8888 "10.1.1.2"
```

Third:

```
python tshark.py temp.pcap 8888 "10.1.1.2" "10.1.1.3"
```